# Unexpected result when comparing two dates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm comparing two dates in this if block:

```
    if(columnsData[i][0] == selectDate){
      todayGeneralCount = todayGeneralCount +1;
      for (var j=0; j<countingByTypeArrays.length; j++) {        
           if(countingByTypeArrays[j][0] == columnsData[i][0]){
              countingByTypeArrays[j][1] == countingByTypeArrays[j][2] +1;             
           }
        else {
             countingByTypeArrays.push([columnsData[i][0], 1]);
      }
    }
  }
```

The condition is always returning `False`. But when I look the logs, I got this:

[image]

This seem to be an unexpected result: both values are `Date` type and have the same value. What is producing this behavior? How to get `True` result?

Comment: FYI: [`[javascript] how to compare two dates`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+compare+two+dates)

Comment: Thanks, @FelixKling, but I'd like to know what is producing this behavior and use this format (which I get from a spreadsheet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One object is never the same as another object ([proof](http://jsfiddle.net/66jD8/)), even if they contain the same value so you have to compare something else, the easiest is to use `getTime()`.

When you use some of the other operators, like `<`, `>`, `<=` etc. comparison does work as `toValue()` is called on the object, but not when using `==` as that just compares the objects, and they are not the same.

```
if(columnsData[i][0].getTime() == selectDate.getTime()){ ...
```

also, inside the condition you're doing

```
if(countingByTypeArrays[j][0] == columnsData[i][0]){
     countingByTypeArrays[j][1] == countingByTypeArrays[j][2] +1;             
}
```

You know you're not setting anything right, as that would be just one equal sign, and you're comparing the values for no apparent reason ?

Comment: Thanks, @adeneo, was a typo the second mistake! I'll try your solution!

Comment: I got this error `TypeError: Cannot find function getTime in object` when I try `columnsData[i][0].getTime()`. Any suggestion?

Comment: If it doesn't have a `getTime()` method, it's not a Date object.

Comment: But the `instanceof Date` returns `True`!

Comment: That's strange? If it's a date object, it should have a `getTime()` method, it's supported in all browsers since the begining of time. A date object in another object shouldn't be an issue either? The only thing I can do is test it, and it seems to work -> http://jsfiddle.net/ERpd8/

Comment: My solution was using `.toString()`. I choose your answer because it put me in the right way! Thanks!